# How to set the RadioButton icon style to nothing in CSS (in Flex 3)?

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex3, radio-button, skinning

You can skin a RadioButton in Flex by setting the following values in CSS:

```
upSkin: Embed(...); 
overSkin: Embed(...);
ownSkin: Embed(...);
disabledSkin: Embed(...);
selectedUpSkin: Embed(...);
selectedOverSkin: Embed(...);
selectedDownSkin: Embed(...);
selectedDisabledSkin: Embed(...);
```

But, it will still display the little circle icon inside your skin. You can change the icon by setting the following styles:

```
upIcon: Embed(...);
overIcon: Embed(...);
etc...
```

My question is, how can I set these icons to nothing? Rather than a 1x1 pixel transparent image or something? How can I give it an empty style?

**Edit:**

In actionscript I can do it like:

```
button.setStyle("icon", null);
```

In CSS I've tried:

```
icon: none;
icon: null;
```

But neither worked.

**Accepted Answer:**

Suggestions [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433654/how-to-set-the-radiobutton-icon-style-to-nothing-in-css-in-flex-3#433852) & [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433654/how-to-set-the-radiobutton-icon-style-to-nothing-in-css-in-flex-3#434540) both worked, but I prefer the cleaner solution of:

```
upIcon: ClassReference(null);
```

Thanks for both answers (wish I could mark both as the answer!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
ClassReference(null);
```

Comment: Used the same but with the skin, worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to set the skin as `null` in Flex CSS. In fact, some Flex component **must** have something set for the skin, and they will throw runtime errors if you use `setStyle("skinName", null)`. I usually use a declaration like this when I want no skin:

```
RadioButton
{
    upIcon: ClassReference("mx.skins.ProgrammaticSkin");
}
```

The `ProgrammaticSkin` class displays nothing and implements `IFlexDisplayObject` (which is often a requirement for skins in Flex), so I think it's the best choice for when you want a blank skin.

Answer (score 1):

If its standard CSS, you can use the following.  I'm assuming the styles are classes, if they're IDs replace the . with a #:

```
.upSkin
{
    background: none;
}
```

The `background` property can be used to set color, positioning, and repeating; if you need to specifically target just the background image use:

```
.upSkin
{
    background-image: none;
}
```