# Changing the appearance of the radio button in Flex 4

Tags: flex4

In Flex 4, how do I change the appearance of a radio button?  I want to change the dot size so it is bigger (ie radius=20) and instead of the label I need to add an image. Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433654/how-to-set-the-radiobutton-icon-style-to-nothing-in-css-in-flex-3

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom Spark `RadioButton` skin class. There is an example to create a multiline  `RadioButton` label at [flexexamples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/04/10/creating-a-multiline-spark-radiobutton-control-in-flex-4/).

Search for the `<!-- dot -->` part in the skin file and replace it with your bigger dot. Create your dot using Adobe Illustrator, or programmatically in Flex using `FXG` or `mxml` (see [Shapes in FXG and MXML graphics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS4D7543E0-0BA2-4f5f-92FA-985B6B6315AB.html)).

Using an image for the label will be more complicated. You will need to define a [custom Skin Part](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder4_skin_parts.html) for your `RadioButton`.